# Problems with sessionid expired django

Tags: django, nginx, cookies, gunicorn, django-sessions

I have a django app, and the autheticate user use the cookies, i set de cookie age with de value 36000

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 36000 #
```

In Google Chrome the cookie **sessionid** set the expired date **1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z**

The app logout in 3 minutes, in other browser have the same problem

In my server i used gunicorn(timeout workers 600s) + nginx(keep_alive_timeout 20m)

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The expiry date of `1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z` appears to be [an issue in Chrome] when it is a browser length cookie that expires when the browser is closed. That suggests that you have [`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#session-expire-at-browser-close) set to `True`.

If you didn't close your browser, I can't explain the behaviour of being logged out after 3 minutes, since your `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 36000` is 10 hours.